# Magento 2: buy X items Get Y cheapest items from X free

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I am using extension Amasty Special Promotions https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html .

I need one promotion Like this

Rule Name: Buy 15 get 5 free
Details: If I buy the 15 items then from those 15 the 5 cheapest should be free. And next it should apply on the qty 30 and then 45 and so on.

Current Rule Configurations:

**Conditions:**

```
If cart total quantity >= 15 & category is 342
```

**Actions:**

```
Apply: The Cheapest, also for Buy 1 get 1 free
Discount Amount: 100
Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 3
```

In the current implementation, I get 5 cheapest free items when total quantity is 15 but after that on 18 get one more free and 21 one more free and so on

Question: Is there any way in the current module to get the discount on 15, 30, 45 ... and on each step get 5 cheapest?

Note: I am working on it and my purpose to share here if someone had the same solution then we can share else after I implement I will share here.

**Here is the example**

Promotion rules

1. If the customer will buy the X items then he will get Y cheapest items free
2. The rule should be calculated on buy X,2X,3X,...

**Run time Example**

Rule: Buy 15 get 5 free

Cart:

```
Stage 1:

Item A

    qty: 4

    Price per item: 5



Item B

    qty: 10

    price per item: 10



Discount: 0



Stage 2:

Item A

    qty: 4

    Price per item: 5

Item B

    qty : 11

    price per item: 10

Discount: 25



Stage 3:

Item A

    qty:  7

    Price per item: 5

Item B

    qty : 11

    price per item: 10

Discount: 25



Stage 4:

Item A

    qty:  19

    Price per item: 5

Item B

    qty : 11

    price per item: 10

Discount: 50
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://amasty.com/docs/doku.php?id=magento_2:special-promotions#the_cheapest_also_for_buy_1_get_1_free), In `Discount Qty Step` you need to specify a step by which a discount will be iterated.

So in your it will be:

```
Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 15
```

Comment: I have done that. In this case, I get the first free item when I buy the 15 items. But at this stage, I want to get the 5 free items.

Comment: Can you check this one: https://amasty.com/docs/doku.php?id=magento_2:special-promotions#buy_x_get_y_x_and_y_are_different_products

Comment: I have added one example. In my case, I want to get the discount for the cheapest items in the cart.